# limit max number of rows in a table or inputs to 5 or 10

Tags: vue.js

I'm using laravel and vuejs to create a web application and i need help to make the user (when filling the form) to limit the number of inputs to 5 or 10 i've tried by making a table but didn't know how to limit the max number of rows

Comment: Could you show us the code where you add new inputs/rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve that using a combination of v-for and v-if:

```
v-for="(value, index) in inputs" v-if="index < 5"
```

Althought, keep in mind this doesn't neccessairly prevent more inputs being added, it only hides them.

If you are adding new inputs using a button of some sorts, you should verify the amount of existing inputs on that end instead.

Here's an example of v-for + v-if combo:
https://jsfiddle.net/tz7mLhe8/